# UIDeviceBatteryLevelDidChangeNotification is not calling selector function swift

Tags: ios

Below is the sample code where I am getting this error when battery level is changed. Could you please advise where I am going wrong.

```
2015-05-05 21:18:55.383 BatteryStatusTest[1702:204137] -[NSLayoutConstraint batteryLevelChanged:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x170096670
2015-05-05 21:18:55.395 BatteryStatusTest[1702:204137] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSLayoutConstraint batteryLevelChanged:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x170096670'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1858242d8 0x1970480e4 0x18582b3a4 0x185828154 0x18572accc 0x1857ca2c4 0x185707450 0x186636a80 0x18a29caec 0x1869d5404 0x1857c6dc4 0x1857dba54 0x1857db9b4 0x1857d9934 0x1857052d4 0x18ef1b6fc 0x18a2cafac0x100104bec 0x1976c6a08)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

But when I have placed this code inside ViewController.swift without BatterMonitor delegate and it is working fine.

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "batteryLevelChanged:", name: UIDeviceBatteryLevelDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "batteryLevelChanged:", name: UIDeviceBatteryStateDidChangeNotification, object: nil)

func batteryLevelChanged(notification: NSNotification) {
    //do something
}
```

Sample Code

AppDelegate.swift

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

        //Enable Battery Monitor
        UIDevice.currentDevice().batteryMonitoringEnabled = true

        return true
    }
}
```

ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, BatteryMonitorDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Battery Monitor before start the drive
        let batteryMonitor = BatteryMonitor()
        batteryMonitor.delegate = self
    }

    func batteyLevelIsNotUnderRecommendedLevel(level: Int) {
        println(level)
    }
}
```

BatteryMonitor.swift

```
import UIKit

protocol BatteryMonitorDelegate {
    func batteyLevelIsNotUnderRecommendedLevel (level: Int)
}

struct BatteryMonitorData {
    static let minimumBatteryLevelRequired: Float = 40
}

class BatteryMonitor: NSObject {

    let thisDevice = UIDevice.currentDevice()
    var delegate: BatteryMonitorDelegate?

    override init() {
        super.init()

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "batteryLevelChanged:", name: UIDeviceBatteryLevelDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "batteryLevelChanged:", name: UIDeviceBatteryStateDidChangeNotification, object: nil)

        println(UIDevice.currentDevice().batteryLevel)
    }

    func batteryLevelChanged(notification: NSNotification) {
        if thisDevice.batteryLevel <= BatteryMonitorData.minimumBatteryLevelRequired {
            delegate?.batteyLevelIsNotUnderRecommendedLevel(Int(thisDevice.batteryLevel * 100))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I could able to solve this issue by inheriting UIResponder for custom Battery Monitor instead of NSObject

Answer (score 1):

You have serveral problems here...

First is that you instantiate your BatteryMonitor but don't hold it.

Second, you keep a strong reference to your delegate inside BatteryMonitor, which is in general a bad idea cause that would lead to a retain cycle

That's why at the time the notification is fired, the thing behind batteryMonitor is already something else

So make the delegate weak and in the deinit of BatteryMonitor remove your NSNotification observing...

Hope it helps...